# Ajax is not passing values to php file

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I've been trying to solve this for hours - any help would be appreciated! I've got a (long) array of checkboxes in a form. Omitting most, let's say my html is:

```
<form name="SelectCategories" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="category[A]" value="A" id="A" /><label for="A">A</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="category[B]" value="B" id="B" /><label for="B">B</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="category[C]" value="C" id="C" /><label for="C">C</label>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
</form>

<div id="display">Select something</div>
```

I have some PHP beneath this:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(0);
$categoriesarray=implode(',',$_POST['category']);
echo $categoriesarray;
?>
```

Then I have some JQuery, to transfer the categoriesarray to a php page. (For some reason the echo above doesn't always work when the JQuery is pasted in, but sometimes does).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").on("submit", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $ajax.({url:"Data.php", type:"POST", data:{data1 : '<?php echo $categoriesarray; ?'>}, success: function(result){
            $("#display").html(result);
        }});
    });
})
```

Finally, my Data.php file (ignoring all the password stuff) is:

```
    <?php
    $list= $_POST['data1'];
    $cxn=mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database)
    or die("Not connected");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1 in ($list) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10";
    $result = mysqli_query($cxn,$query)
    or die("Select something");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo $row['columnname'];

    }
?>
```

The idea is that it pulls out 10 random database entries which have the value "1" in the checked categories. However, I only get "Select something" returned in my display div.

Weirdly, if I delete something on the html page, refresh the html page, put the code back in and refresh it again, the whole thing works perfectly. But if I connect to the page by going through the address bar - instead of refreshing - I just get "select something" returned when I press submit, instead of data from the database.

Any ideas what's going wrong?!

Comment: Change the name of your checkboxes elements to `category[]`

Comment: the usual way to debug these kind of errors is: open your network tab, check the request and the response each time you send it. check if the correct values are passed and if php evaluates those correctly.

Comment: Have you run the php file by itself to see what it returns?

Comment: Krister - that doesn't make a difference unfortunately (there is a separate reason I've got it in there, but it makes no change...)

Comment: TimSPQR - Yep - if I change the line in my php file to $list="A,B,C" it works fine. So the problem definitely lies with transferring the categories from my html form to the php file - I just don't know where...

Comment: You do realize that you're suppressing potential errors using `error_reporting(0);`. Use `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to understand what exactly is being done here, but here are some things to consider:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(0);
$categoriesarray=implode(',',$_POST['category']);
echo $categoriesarray;
?>
```

Are you POSTing anything at this stage?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("form").on("submit", function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$ajax.({url:"Data.php", type:"POST", data:{data1 : '<?php echo 
$categoriesarray; ?'>}, success: function(result){
$("#display").html(result);
}});
});
})
```

With this AJAX, you are putting a PHP echo directly into the object it's sending.. You should instead be collecting which checkboxes are ticked by the user, no?

Something like:

```
$("form").on("submit", function(e){
var data = $( "form" ).serialize();
e.preventDefault();
$ajax.({url:"Data.php", type:"POST", data: data}, success: function(result){
$("#display").html(result);
}});
});
```

Now, you're getting an array in PHP which you can mess with and get the relevant data.
And generally, you want to just do category[] and let it work itself out.

If you think I'm misunderstanding your intentions, I do apologize, but I just can't make sense of it.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting, Voltlight, but I don't think that's the problem. If I do:

Comment: See, what I'm getting from this, is AJAX is never actually sending information from the user. It's sending a string put there by PHP at the start. Also, I don't think you can post code markup in here.